# Play framework: How to reference image from javascript file

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set an image in a static js script but it doesn't work.

```
var _pointer = document.createElement("DIV");
_pointer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/repeater_1x4.jpg)';
```

It returns this error:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/images/repeater_1x4.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried the following since I have static resources mapped from the public folder to the assets/ url path, it doesn't returns any errors, but again it doesn't show the image.

```
var _pointer = document.createElement("DIV");
_pointer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(@routes.Assets.at("images/repeater_1x4.jpg"))';
```

In case you're wondering this is in my routes file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

What's the correct way to do this? I'm using Play! 2.0, my scripts are in public/javascripts and my images are in public/images as you might expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
_pointer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/assets/images/repeater_1x4.jpg)';
```